# Keep dropdown menu (Language Picker) always visible on the right side of the nav in Bootstrap 4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, navbar

I am trying to place a dropdown just before the hamburger button. The challenge is to keep it visible in the same place even when the navbar collapses.
Even though I'm placing it ouside the collapse navbar-collapse div, it always collapses with the other nav elements. 
Is there a better solution than position:absolute?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top" id="navbar">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="#" alt="" id="logo">
    </a>

    <button class="navbar-toggler hamburger hamburger--slider" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"  id="toggleNav">
<span class="hamburger-box">
<span class="hamburger-inner" ></span>
</span>
    </button> 
    <div class="language-picker">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="index.html" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Language
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">English</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">French</a>
                    <!-- <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">THE BEST SOLUTION</a> -->
            </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#"><span>CONTACT</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#"><span>LOGIN</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link chatIcon" href="#"><img src="img/icons/account_icon.png" alt="a chat icon"></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- end collapse navbar-collapse -->
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the dropdown and toggler together in 1 div...

https://www.codeply.com/go/H19BTH57m4

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top" id="navbar">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="//placehold.it/30" alt="" id="logo">
    </a>
    <div class="d-flex flex-row">
        <div class="language-picker">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle mr-2" href="index.html" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Language
                </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">English</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">French</a>
                        <!-- <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">THE BEST SOLUTION</a> -->
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <button class="navbar-toggler hamburger hamburger--slider" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" id="toggleNav">
            <span class="hamburger-box navbar-toggler-icon">
            <span class="hamburger-inner"></span>
            </span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#"><span>CONTACT</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#"><span>LOGIN</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link chatIcon" href="#"><img src="//placehold.it/30" alt="a chat icon"></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- end collapse navbar-collapse -->
</nav>
```

Another option is to use `ml-auto` on the dropdown, and remove it from the `navbar-nav`: https://www.codeply.com/go/rtmowu5Bl9